# Group by and concatenation in OBI 10g analytics

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence

I have a problem in OBI analytics. I'm using OBI 10g.

I have two columns: `ID` and `supervisorID`. 
As a result I want two columns:
1. the `ID` 
2. and the concatenation of all the `supervisorID` of the `ID` in a second column.

So If I have ID following data:

```
ID     supervisorID
1      3
1      4
2      4
```

I want as a result:

```
ID     concat(supervisor)
1      3;4
2      4
```

I don't want to change anything at the `RPD`, so my question is if this is possible in analytics itself?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a crude answer, but I think it will work

`SELECT A.USER_ID,
       SUBSTR(A.SUPERVISORID, 0, LENGTH(A.SUPERVISORID) - 1) AS SUPERVISORID
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT S.USER_ID,
                        (xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getXML('SELECT S1.SUPERVISORID||'';'' AS VAL_1
                 FROM SO_19 S1
                 WHERE S1.USER_ID = ''' || S.USER_ID ||'''')) . EXTRACT('//VAL_1/text()')
                        .getStringval()) AS SUPERVISORID
          FROM SO_19 S) A`